# how to track number of sessions in Glassfish instance?

Tags: glassfish-3

We used to use WebObject servers to host our apps. Now moving to Glassfish is quite interesting. WebObject used to let us see how many transactions and sessions were being handled by each instance. How do i go about this in Glassfish?

Answer (score 11):

You can view statistics in the Glassfish Admin Console. You've to activate the monitoring first:

`Configurations` -> `server-config` -> `Monitoring` -> Set Monitoring level to `HIGH` for `Web Container`

Now you can see the statistics under `server` -> `Monitor`

[image: glassfish monitoring]

You can also retrieve statistics via asadmin command, for more information [check this](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19798-01/821-1751/ghqfr/index.html).

Comment: Is there anyway to do this programmatically?